# How to concatenate json array values via "|"?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have colunn with jsonb format. Columns name is "column1" and table is "table1"

```
{
.....
"source_types": {
  "source_type_os": [ ,

      1,3,5
    ],
   ....
  },
  ....
}
```

I can take string of array like "[1,3,5]" but i need to get something like 1|3|5

I have tryed this code

```
select ....
       t1.column1::jsonb #>>'{source_types,source_type_os}' as "test", <--here the problem
       ....
from table1 t1
where ....;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ....
       replace(trim(both '[]' from t1.column1::jsonb #>>'{source_types,source_type_os}'),',','|') as "test",
       ....
from table1 t1
where ....;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ....
       string_agg(c.col, '|') as "test"
  from table1 as t1
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(t1.column1::jsonb #>>'{source_types,source_type_os}') as c(col)
 group by t1
```

Comment: group by breaks everything, how can id do it without group by?